# How to get grandchild elements from Elementtree in python

Tags: python, elementtree

Say I have an XML code like this one:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
           ....
        </b>
        <c>
           ....
        </c>
        <d>
           ....
        </d>
    </a>
    <d><c></c><a></a></d>
</root>
```

Is there a function to get the grandchildren elements given a certain child node?
Foe example, in the XML code above, if I pass 'd', I would like it to return 'c' and 'a'.

I tried getChildren(), but I guess this returns attributes, but not the children elements. I don't even have attributes btw.

Thank you.

Comment: getChildren does return child elements. And why are you guessing it is returning attributes, when you don't have attributes?

Comment: @zaphod, it didn't return anything when I tried... let me explain what I did. As in the example above, say <d> is the root element, and I want its child elements. I did, list = d.getChildren(). the d here is whatever was return after I did child.tag

Answer (score 3):

The root element is iterable:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xml = "<root><a><b>....</b><c>....</c><d>....</d></a><d><c></c><a></a></d></root>"
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> root
<Element 'root' at 0x7fa86a7ea610>
>>> for child in root:
...     print(child)
... 
<Element 'a' at 0x7fa86a7ea650>
<Element 'd' at 0x7fa86a7ea810>
```

### Getting specific grandchild elements:

```
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> root.find("d")
[<Element 'd' at 0x10d7869a8>]
```

The `find()` method will find the first matching child. Note how this is only the child element. We can find grandchildren elements by iterating the child:

```
>>> for e in root.find("d"):
...     print(e)
...
<Element 'c' at 0x10d82ec28>
<Element 'a' at 0x10d82ec78>
```

If you want the tag rather than the ElementTree object:

```
>>> [e.tag for e in root.find("d")]
['c', 'a']
```

Note that `<Element 'c' at 0x7fce44939650>` represents an ElementTree `Element` object (same as `root`), whose API is defined [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that's not what I asked. You code returns only a and d. What I want to accomplish is when I pass d, I would like to get c and a. Look at the example, d is already a child element, and I want to get, maybe I should say, grandchildren of that child element.

Comment: root.getchildren() also returns a list of child elements

Comment: @Nayana: [i.getchildren() for i in root.find('d')] is probably what you want!

Comment: @zaphod, Thank you so much for your help. I tried. That only return 'd' and its memory address... I guess there is no function that return a list of grandchildren given a child element?

Comment: These are not memory addresses. They're python objects. you can call all the same methods on them as you would on the root element.

Comment: FYI, `getchildren` is deprecated, one should just call `list`/`iter` on the object now: `list(root.find("d"))` now

Comment: Thanks @SeanBreckenridge, Just fixed it for the new API version.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `root` is the root of your tree:

```
>>> [grchild for child in root for grchild in child]
[<Element 'b' at 0xb6cbad4c>, <Element 'c' at 0xb6cbaedc>,
<Element 'd' at 0xb6cbad24>, <Element 'c' at 0xb6cbaaa4>]
```

Ok so let's write a recursive function the Haskell way:

```
def recurse(node):
    for child in node:
        print(child)
        recurse(child)

>>> node = root.find('d')
>>> recurse(node)
<Element 'c' at 0xb6cbaaa4>
<Element 'a' at 0xb6cbac0c>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but that certainly isn't what I am trying to do... if you look at the example XML code, when I pass the second root element, which is 'd', I want to get its grand children, which are 'a' and 'c'.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily pass a level n tag name. You will need to know the xpath for that and give the xpath to the find method!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already, parsed the document,  `[i.getchildren() for i in root.findall('d')]` is probably what you want!

To be more generic, you can have a function

```
def getGrandChildOfTag(tagName, root):
    return [i.getchildren() for i in root.findall(tagName)]
```

Comment: I really think that getChildren() returns attributes, because when I ran it, it gave me "AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getChildren'"

Comment: First of all, it is getchildren and not getChildren. Secondly, the attribute error is a python error thrown because you tried to invoke a method which does not belong to the object. It has nothing to do with xml attributes!