# Python lxml accessing grandchild tag

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an xml file (sample below). I cannot for the life of me access the grandchild tag. I've also included my attempt. I've been trying to get the correct answer by looking at lxml xpath strucutres and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294093/how-to-get-grandchild-elements-from-elementtree-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer.

Could someone point my in the right direction? My output csv only returns the headers.

Thanks

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/UserProfile/v2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ProfileExtension/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityGoals/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">

<Trackpoint>
    <Time>2018-04-13T13:06:10Z</Time>
    <DistanceMeters>80.14</DistanceMeters>
    <Cadence>5</Cadence>
    <Extensions>
        <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
             <Speed>2.01</Speed>
            <Watts>2</Watts>
        </TPX>
     </Extensions>
    <HeartRateBpm>
         <Value>96</Value>
    </HeartRateBpm>
    </Trackpoint>
```

My attempted solution:

```
 import lxml.etree as et
 import csv

 x = et.parse('sample.tcx', parser = et.XMLParser(remove_comments = True))
 y = et.tostring(x, pretty_print = True, encoding = 'unicode')
 #root = x.getroot()

NS = 'http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2'
NS2 = 'http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2'
header1 = ('Speed', 'Watts')

with open('output1.csv', 'w') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    writer.writerow(header1)
    root = et.fromstring(y)
    for item in root.iter('./Trackpoint/Extensions/TPX {%s}' % NS2):
        Speed = item.find('Speed').text #3
        Watts = item.find('Watts').text #3

        row = Speed, Watts
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: 1. By "grandchild tag", do you mean `TPX`? 2. The sample XML document looks incomplete. You have `NS = 'http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2'` in the code, but that namespace is not used in the XML.

Comment: `TPX` is bound to the `http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2` namespace, which is declared in the XML document but not in the Python code.

Comment: @mzjn, I'm looking to access the values in Speed and Watts and then HeartRateBpm. In my fugue state I didn't even realize the text string was different. I have updated the namespace (included a NS2) but a still no values are being returned.

Comment: The XML sample is still incomplete. There is no declaration of `http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2`.

Comment: Ok I understand, in my actual file the namespace is included, there's actually a few of them: xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/UserProfile/v2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ProfileExtension/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityGoals/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDat...

Comment: Please edit the question instead of showing all those namespaces in a comment. And the code related to writing CSV seems irrelevant to the XML problem. Try to trim the code down to the essentials (create a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with BeautifulSoup, it's not ideal as I have to convert all elements to strings and then strip characters, but it will do for now.

```
import lxml.etree as et
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

time = []

data = open('sample.tcx', 'r')
soup = Soup(data, 'lxml-xml')

for i in soup.find_all('Time'):
    time.append((i))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested this is how I managed to parse and clean the tcx file format.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import pandas as pd

data = open('jc180512.tcx', 'r')
soup = Soup(data, 'lxml-xml')

time = []
dist = []
caden = []
speed = []
watts = []
hrbpm = []
hrbp = [0 for i in range(6)] # hardcoded a number of zeros at the
```

start of the heartbeat col as the measurements are not made until the 6th cycle.

```
for i in soup.find_all('Time'):
    time.append((i))

for i in soup.find_all('DistanceMeters'):
    dist.append(i)

for i in soup.find_all('Cadence'):
    caden.append(i)

for i in soup.find_all('Speed'):
    speed.append(i)

for i in soup.find_all('Watts'):
    watts.append(i)

for i in soup.find_all('Value'):
    hrbpm.append(i)

heartrate = hrbp + hrbpm 

f = open("test.csv", "w")
for i in range(len(time)):
    f.write("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n".format(time[i], dist[i], caden[i], speed[i], watts[i]))
f.close()

g = open('test0.csv', 'w')
for i in range(len(heartrate)):
    g.write('{}\n'.format(heartrate[i]))
g.close

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header = None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test0.csv', header = None)

all_data = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

all_data = all_data.fillna(0)

all_data = all_data.astype(str)

all_data[0] = all_data[0].applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('<Time>').rstrip('</Time>'))
all_data[0] = all_data[0].applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('<Value>').rstrip('</Value>'))
all_data[0] = all_data[0].applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip('Z'))
all_data[0] = all_data[0].applymap(lambda x: x.replace('T', ' '))
all_data[1] = all_data[1].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('</DistanceMeters>').lstrip(' <DistanceMeters>'))
all_data[2] = all_data[2].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(' <Cadence>').rstrip('</Cadence>'))
all_data[3] = all_data[3].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(' <ns3:Speed>').rstrip('</ns3:Speed>'))
all_data[4] = all_data[4].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(' <ns3:Watts>').rstrip('</ns3:Watts>'))

all_data.to_csv('final.csv', index = False)

with open('final.csv') as inf:
    with open('output_1.csv', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            outf.write(','.join(line.split(' ')))
```